# Example 1.5-9 in Kreyszig's INTRODUCTORY FUNCTIONAL ANALYSIS WITH APPLICATIONS: How to construct such examples?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

Let $X$ denote the set of all the real (or complex) valued continuous functions on the closed interval $[0, 1]$, and let $$ d(x, y) \colon= \int_0^1 \lvert x(t) - y(t) \rvert \ \mathrm{d} t $$
for all $x, y \in X$. This $d$ is a metric on $X$, and $(X, d)$ is not complete, as has been shown by Kreyszig, for the sequence $\left( x_n \right)$, where 
$$ x_n (t) \colon= 
\begin{cases} 
0 \ & \mbox{ if } \ 0 \leq t \leq \frac{1}{2}, \\ 
(m+2)\left( t - \frac{1}{2} \right) \ & \mbox{ if } \ \frac{1}{2} \leq t \leq \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{m+2}, \\
1 \ & \mbox{ if } \ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{m+2} \leq t \leq 1, 
\end{cases}
$$
for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, is a Cauchy sequence that fails to converge to any point $x$ in $(X, d)$.

Now my question is, what is the gist of the process involved in the  construction of such examples? I mean what do we need to look for in the functions $x_n$ that would constitute a Cauchy but not a convergent sequence?

Another example given by Kreyszig is in Prob. 13, Sec. 1.5. Here $x_n$ is defined as 
$$ x_n(t) \colon= \begin{cases}
 n \ & \mbox{ if } \ 0 \leq t \leq n^{-2}, \\ 
t^{-1/2} \ & \mbox{ if } \ n^{-2} \leq t \leq 1.  
 \end{cases} 
$$
What is the gist of examples like this one?

How do we generalise each one of these two examples to an arbitrary closed interval $[a, b]$, where $a$ and $b$ are some real numbers such that $a < b$?

Comment: Just looking at the definition of the first sequence, you can see that it will converge to a function that jumps from $0$ to $1$ in the point $\frac{1}{2}$. Clearly such a function is discontinuous. The location of the jump is totally irrelavent. You can generalize this to arbitrary intervals by just placing the jump somewhere in the interval.

Comment: Before you can construct such examples you need some feeling for the metric. Here, the metric 'sums' all vertical differences between functions. The first sequence compresses the vertical differences to smaller and smaller intervals. In the limit, the 'sum' doesn't notice the vertical differences because the difference is confined to a set of measure zero.

Comment: Anyways, the idea of the counterexample here is to construct a Cauchy sequence converging to a function that does not belong to your space. What would happen if we extend the space to integrable functions in stead of continuous functions? Is the metric still well-defined? Is the space complete? Is it the completion of the original space? These are good questions to get some feeling for this subject.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud see this    playlist..In particlular see the videos from 112 to 116..i think this will  help you more in  how to construct such counterexamples https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=etP21xln8iQ&list=PLAvgI3H-gclZa-DVTMyUIAxM-X8NSikwu

Answer (score 1):

The completion of this space under the given $L^1[0,1]$ metric is all of $L^1[0,1]$, which is just about as classical as it gets. So if you construct a sequence $\{ f_n \}$ in $C[0,1]$ that converges in this metric to some $f \in L^1[0,1]$ which is not equal a.e. to some $\tilde{f} \in C[0,1]$, then $\{ f_n \}$ will be Cauchy in the metric, but it will not be able to converge to any $g\in C[0,1]$ in this metric because of uniqueness of $L^1$ limits. So that's the intuition, and it's a proof if you know such facts about $L^1[0,1]$.